AttributeError: module 'lxml.html.clean' has no attribute 'defs' on Odoo 17
I get an error when installing lxml on an Odoo 17 project in MacBook M1 chip.
When installing requirements.txt, an error occurred so I commented out some lines in the requirements.txt file:
...
#greenlet==1.1.2 ; python_version == '3.10'  # (Jammy)
#greenlet==2.0.2 ; python_version > '3.10'
...
#lxml==4.8.0 ; python_version <= '3.10'
#lxml==4.9.2 ; python_version > '3.10'
...
#reportlab==3.6.8 ; python_version <= '3.10'
#reportlab==3.6.12 ; python_version > '3.10'
...

After uninstalling all packages, I tried to reinstall them manually.
I was able to install the greenlet and reportlab packages but, not the lxml package.
According to this Odoo 17 install bug discussion, the problem is due to the lxml version. I tried to install lxml 4.8.0 version using pip3 install lxml==4.8.0, but I get an other error. Then I ran pip3 install lxml and lxml 5.2.1 was installed.
When running an Odoo project in PyCharm, this error occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from . import modules
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry, neutralize
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 11, in <module>
    import odoo.tools as tools
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .mail import *
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo/tools/mail.py", line 19, in <module>
    from lxml.html import clean
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/lxml/html/clean.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: lxml.html.clean module is now a separate project lxml_html_clean.
Install lxml[html_clean] or lxml_html_clean directly.

When I tried the pip3 install  lxml[html_clean] command, I get on command prompt
zsh: no matches found: lxml[html_clean].
I tried to install lxml_html_clean and the installation was successful.
However, after this installation, I tried to run Odoo project and I got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from . import modules
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry, neutralize
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 11, in <module>
    import odoo.tools as tools
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .mail import *
  File "/Users/youstra/odoo-server/odoo/tools/mail.py", line 32, in <module>
    safe_attrs = clean.defs.safe_attrs | frozenset(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'lxml.html.clean' has no attribute 'defs'

I am using:

Python version: 3.12
Odoo version: 17
iOS version: Sonoma


Please use python version 3.11 for Odoo v17 and try to install packages using the virtual environment.

Downgrading to this version seems to resolve this issue:
pip install lxml==5.1.0

Great!
The problem was about python version. I switch to python 3.10 version and the problem was solved
